# Nested while loops stop after first iteration?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, nested

I'm trying to compare values using a table "charms" but my outer 3 loops will only register the first iteration; only the innermost loop compares all values.

```
while (m < 17) {
        while (n < 17) {
            while (o < 17) {
                while (p < 17) {
                    number = (Math.pow(w, charms[m]))
                            * (Math.pow(x, charms[n]))
                            * (Math.pow(y, charms[o]))
                            * (Math.pow(z, charms[p]));
                    if (Math.abs(cons - number) < Math.abs(cons - closest)) {
                        closest = number;
                        a = charms[m];
                        b = charms[n];
                        c = charms[o];
                        d = charms[p];
                    }
                    p++;
                }
                o++;
            }
            n++;
        }
        m++;
    }
```

Comment: What diagnostic steps have you taken? What are the initial values of `m`, `n`, `o` and `p`? Is there an exception? Basically there's too little information here to help you.

Comment: shouldn't you change that to a while loop that encapsulates all those values? i mean while( m < 17 && n < 17 && o < 17 && p < 17 ) instead of that giant thing?

Comment: When `p==17`, it never gets reset to whatever initial value it had. The outer loops are useless after the first run.

Comment: Rewrite it using `for` loop and it will be easier for you to see the logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you do not show how you initialize `m, n, o and p`. Secondly, you are not resetting the counters at any point. Once you go through the most inner loop once, you will never go through it again since `p` will be greater than or equal to 17 after that. Then once `o` reaches 17, you will never go into that loop again and so on.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I forgot to do something that simple.

Comment: @user2785277 I've been programming for 36 years and I still do things like that sometimes.  In fact, I caught one just last week where I forgot to increment something inside a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what the initial values of `m`, `n`, `o`, and `p` are, and what the values of `charms` are.  But there's a simple reason this won't work: Say `m`, `n`, `o`, and `p` are all set to 1 before the loop.  Then the inner loop executes and exits when `p` is 17.  So then you increment `o` and start that loop over--but what is `p`?  It's still 17!  It's never set back down to 1 or whatever.  So none of the code in the innermost loop ever ever ever executes again.

At the very least, you need to reset each variable before you loop on it:

```
 while (m < 17) {
    n = 1;  // or whatever, you haven't told us what it's supposed to start at
    while (n < 17) {
        o = 1;
        while (o < 17) {
            p = 1;
            while (p < 17) {
```

or even better, use `for` loops which put the initialize, test, and increment logic all in one place.